Integrated App Not Showing in Workflow with Custom Object
I am encountering an issue with my integrated app within HubSpot workflows and need some assistance.
Issue Details:
When I start a workflow using a predefined object, the integrated app appears and functions correctly.
When I start a workflow using a custom object, the integrated app does not show up.
Additionally, as the owner of the integrated app, I cannot find it listed when attempting to install it during a workflow initiated by a custom object.
Steps to Reproduce:
Start a workflow using a custom object.
Attempt to install the integrated app during this workflow.
Notice that the integrated app is not listed or available for selection.
Has anyone else encountered this issue or can provide some guidance on resolving it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!
Tried to change some scopes and republish the app. But it didnt work
